# Dynamically Create Variable/Method Names

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here is possibly a very simple question that I am trying to figure out. I find myself constantly running into.  Take the following block of JavaScript/jQuery:

```
 $('#image1Path').change(change => {
      if(this.selectedImage1 == "None"){
        $("#image1Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/NoImageSelected.png");
      } else {
        $("#image1Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/product-images/" + this.selectedImage1);
      }
    });

    $('#image2Path').change(change => {
      if(this.selectedImage2 == "None"){
        $("#image2Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/NoImageSelected.png");
      } else {
        $("#image2Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/product-images/" + this.selectedImage2);
      }
    });

    $('#image3Path').change(change => {
      if(this.selectedImage3 == "None"){
        $("#image3Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/NoImageSelected.png");
      } else {
        $("#image3Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/product-images/" + this.selectedImage3);
      }
    });

    $('#image4Path').change(change => {
      if(this.selectedImage4 == "None"){
        $("#image4Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/NoImageSelected.png");
      } else {
        $("#image4Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/product-images/" + this.selectedImage4);
      }
    });

    $('#image5Path').change(change => {
      if(this.selectedImage5 == "None"){
        $("#image5Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/NoImageSelected.png");
      } else {
        $("#image5Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/product-images/" + this.selectedImage5);
      }
    });

    $('#image6Path').change(change => {
      if(this.selectedImage6 == "None"){
        $("#image6Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/NoImageSelected.png");
      } else {
        $("#image6Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/product-images/" + this.selectedImage6);
      }
    });
```

This is obviously super repetitive and unnecessary.  It would of course make sense to create some kind of loop to handle it instead.  Something that looks like this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    $("#image" + i + "Path").change(change => {
       if(this.*selectedImage + i* == "None"){
          $("#image" + i + "Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/product-images/" + *this.selectedImage + i*);
       } else {
          $("#image" + i + "Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/NoImageSelected.png");
       }
    }
}
```

I know this doesn't work.  The problem is of course that you can't concatenate the i variable name and the selectedImage variable name, in some manner like what is seen above between the asterisks.  I'm kind of curious if there is some way around this, or if there actually is a way to dynamically create variable/method names.  Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just put the `this.selectedImage5` thing into an array, so you could just do `something[i]` instead? Another method would be to use eval, but it's really hard to give you some good ideas on relatively still vague information Maybe some html would help

Comment: If you can, change the IDs to ImagePath<x>, then you can add the single change function to all IDs starting with "imagepath" using a single selector. You can query the actual ID for the number inside the function

Answer (score 1):

You can use single `change` handler with attribute begins with selector as parameter to `jQuery()`, get digit character from `change.target.id`, use bracket notation, string concatenation or template literal

```
 const path = "../../assets/images/";
 $("[id^=image]").change(change => {
   let n = change.target.id.replace(/\D/g, "");
   let curr = $(`#${change.target.id.replace(/Path/, "Display")}`);
   let selected = this[`selectedImage${n}`];
   curr.attr("src", selected == "None" 
     ? `${path}/NoImageSelected.png`
     : `${path}/product-images/${selected}`);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

We can access variable like object[variablename]

```
function bindEvent(i){
          $("#image" + i + "Path").change(change => {
               if(this[selectedImage + i] == "None"){
                  $("#image" + i + "Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/product-images/" + this[selectedImage + i]);
               } else {
                  $("#image" + i + "Display").attr("src", "../../assets/images/NoImageSelected.png");
               }
            }
        }

    for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
      bindEvent(i);
    }
```